# Raid backup replacement for IBM x3250 M2 (4194 K1G)

Tags: ibm, hardware-raid

I have an x3250 M2 4194 K1G with an LSI Logic 1064e SAS/SATA controller on board. System setup with RAID 1 and going good. In case it going bad and controller will destroy itself to liberate planet from invaders i need to plan hardware replacement.

As long as i do my research (about 3 days now) i get next simple results:

1. IBM has PN for obfuscated "SAS/SATA controller" - 43V7415 on IBM x3250 M2 4194
2. I did not find an replacement PN for obfuscated "SAS/SATA controller"
3. I found replacement PN for ServeRAID BR10il. It will do work (in theory), but will cost more.

So, my questions is

1. How (or where) to find an
   replacement PN for LSI Logic 1064e
   SAS/SATA controller?
2. Will emergency replacement LSI Logic
   1064e on ServeRAID BR10il work good or
   should i brace myself for impact?

Answer (score 1):

A failure of the actual *controller card* is exceedingly unlikely, and if you keep a spare sitting in a closet its battery will almost certainly be dead when you want to use it.  I suggest you plan for more likely failures, like a disk dying.

Re: your questions --

1. If you need a replacement part for any IBM device you should contact IBM with the model & serial number for your device - they will be able to supply any replacements you need within reason.
2. You should always be prepared for the worst. Make backups of your data regularly so you can recover in the event of a catastrophic failure.
   ***RAID is NOT a backup***

Comment: Agreed RAID is not a backup. You need either a rotating copy, or a synchronized duplicate for protection on some other medium.